# Why is $x(t):=|t|^a$ not an element of $D$? (Synthetic Differential Geometry)

Tags: infinitesimals, synthetic-differential-geometry

If $a \in (1/2,1)$ then $x(t):=|t|^a$ is not element of $D$ but $x^2=0$ in *$R$.

Why is it so?

Thanks.